# Best way to migrate an IntelliJ project to Maven?

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

I have a project that uses the built-in IntelliJ build system. What's the quickest/best way to migrate the project to Maven?

Answer (score 4):

> What's the quickest/best way to migrate the project to Maven?

Manually. Here is what I would do (I would personally use the command line):

- create a parallel (potentially multi-modules) project structure using archetype(s)
- declare dependencies for the jars you're using (not all of them, you'll get some transitively)
- move sources and resources to the new structure
- test the build
- import the project back into your IDE

Answer (score 1):

IDEA understands Maven very well. Unfortunately it does not create Maven configuration for you.

You'll have to write `pom.xml` yourself. The complexity of this depend on the structure of you project and frameworks/libraries that you use.

For me the easiest way is to create a new project based on artifact and then copy existing source files into it. You can do this in IDEA:

1. File -> New project -> Create project from Scratch
2. Choose `Maven module`, Next
3. Check `Create from Artifact`: a list of available artifact will show. Choose one based on libraries/frameworks you use. You can also add one if it's not on the list (search the web).
4. When project setup is done, start copying sources.